# How to render the Sea depth level in different color?

Tags: qgis, symbology, api, c++

I would Like to adapt an old code in c++ using the api qgis 1.6 :

```
const QgsRenderer* lrenderer = pLayer->renderer();
if( lrenderer == NULL )
    lrenderer = new QgsSingleSymbolRenderer( pLayer->geometryType() );
QList<QgsSymbol*> lSymbols      = lrenderer->symbols();
QgsSymbol* lsy = lSymbols.at(0);
lrenderer = new QgsUniqueValueRenderer( QGis::Polygon );
QStringList lListValue; lListValue  << "0" << "3" << "5"<< "10";
for(int i = 0 ; i < lListValue.size() ; i++) {
    QgsSymbol* newsymbol = new QgsSymbol( *lsy);
    newsymbol->setLowerValue( QString::number(i) );
    newsymbol->setFillColor(QColor(115, 182, 239));
    newsymbol->setColor( QColor(125, 137, 140) );
    newsymbol->setLineWidth(0.3);
    ((QgsUniqueValueRenderer*)lrenderer)->insertValue( lListValue.at(i), newsymbol ); //A
}
((QgsUniqueValueRenderer*)lrenderer)->updateSymbolAttributes(); //B
((QgsUniqueValueRenderer*)lrenderer)->setClassificationField(lMapField.value("DRVAL2").toInt() ); //C
```

This is a qgis api 1.6 c++ code
Now I want to do the same thing using the qgis 2.8.2 api c++
I have started to code it :

```
lrenderer = QgsFeatureRendererV2::defaultRenderer( QGis::Polygon );
QList<QgsSymbolV2*>         lSymbols    = lrenderer->symbols();
QList<QgsSymbolV2*>         lSymbolsToRender    = lrenderer->symbols();
QStringList lListValue;
lListValue  << "0" << "3" << "5"<< "10";

for(int i = 0 ; i < lListValue.size() ; i++) {
    QgsSymbolV2* newsymbol = lSymbols.at(0);
    QgsSymbolLayerV2List  lSymbolLayerList = newsymbol->symbolLayers();
    QgsLineSymbolV2 *MyLine = new QgsLineSymbolV2(lSymbolLayerList);
    MyLine->setWidth(0.3);
    QgsSymbolLayerV2 * lSymbolLayer;
    lSymbolLayer = lSymbolLayerList.at(0);
    lSymbolLayer->setFillColor(QColor(115, 182, 239));
    lSymbolLayer->setColor( QColor(125, 137, 140) );
    newsymbol->insertSymbolLayer(lListValue.at(i).toInt(), lSymbolLayer);
    lSymbolsToRender.append(newsymbol);
}
```

I don't know how i can code the A, B and C comment of the old code ?
Does anyone have sample on how to renderer the deep of the sea with different color, ie level 0 is light blue 10 feet deep is blue and more is dark blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that could be used.

The code is base on the reading of a s57 map .

```
QList<QgsSymbolV2*>         lSymbols    = lrenderer->symbols();
QList<QgsSymbolV2*>         lSymbolsToRender    = lrenderer->symbols();
QStringList lListValue;
lListValue  << "0" << "3" << "5" << "10" << "15" << "20" << "30" << "35" << "40" << "50" << "100" << "200";

QStringList MyColor;
MyColor << "#b4e6ee" << "#a0c8ee" << "#82a0ee" << "#6478ee" << "#646eee" << "#6464ee" << "#5a64ee" << "#505aee" << "#5050ee"<< "#4646ee"<< "#3c46ee"<< "#3c3cee";
QList<QgsRendererCategoryV2> Categories;

qDebug() << "ColorSize =" << QString::number(MyColor.size()) << "   ValueSize=" << QString::number(lListValue.size());
for(int i = 0 ; i < lListValue.size() ; i++) {
    QgsSymbolV2* newsymbol = QgsSymbolV2::defaultSymbol(QGis::Polygon );
    newsymbol->setColor(QColor(MyColor.at(i)));
    qDebug() << "i=" << QString::number(i) << "   listValue=" << lListValue.at(i) << "  color=" <<MyColor.at(i);
    QgsRendererCategoryV2 MyCategorie = QgsRendererCategoryV2(QVariant( lListValue.at(i) ),newsymbol,lListValue.at(i));
    Categories.append(MyCategorie);
}
lrenderer = new QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2("DRVAL1",Categories);
pLayer->setRendererV2(lrenderer);
```